# A better way to handle updating state in reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I'm trying to learn `react-redux` and in my reducer `GET_COMMENTS`. I need to check first if there is already items in `state.comments` so I try to use `if-else` statement and it works. But maybe there's still a better way to handle it ?

```
case 'GET_COMMENTS':
        let list = []
        if (state.comments.length > 0) { // check if there's an item 
            list = state.comments // pass existing state
            action.payload.data.map(comment => { // map through new data
                list = [...list, comment] // dont know if this is the right way but it works
            })
        } else {
            list = action.payload.data // if state.comments is empty directly pass new data
        }
        return {
            ...state,
            comments: list,
            next: action.payload.next
        }
```

**UPDATE**: I decided to go with `Gabriele` answer as I think its the best approach. And Today I learn that `.concat()` method is used to join two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but returns a new array, containing the values of the joined arrays.

Comment: Not related to your question, but `map` is for creating new array, `forEach` or `for` are better alternative for looping.

Comment: @AjeetShah ah yes my bad. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just do

```
case 'GET_COMMENTS':
  return ({
    ...state,
    comments: state.comments.concat(action.payload.data),
    next: action.payload.next
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is correct. I would simplify your approach to

```
...
case 'GET_COMMENTS':
  return {
    ...state,
    comments: [...state.comments, ...action.payload.data]
    next: action.payload.next
  };
```

Note: I consider that `action.payload.comments` is a new array of comments. And initial state is `{ comments: [] }`.